# Parameterising a curve correctly

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

**Question** Parameterise the curve formed by the intersection of the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$, the cylinder $x^2+y^2=x$ and the halfspace $z \gt 0$

**My attempt:**

The intersection between these curves is $1-z^2=x$, which by using $z^2 = 1-x^2-y^2$, I get $x^2+y^2=x $ which I can parameterise as such 
$$
r(t) = \begin{pmatrix} \frac{1}{2}(\cos(t)+1) \\
\frac{1}{2}\sin(t)\\
\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{2}(\cos(t)+1)}\end{pmatrix}
$$

Would $(t,\sqrt{t-t^2},\sqrt{1-t}$) also be a correct parametrisation?

Would this be a correct parameterisation? What would the limits of t be?

Thank you!

Comment: Two quick comments: 1. Your trig parametrization is correct, but the third coordinate can be simplified a bit (or rather a lot if you use a half-angle formula); 2. Your square root parametrization covers only half the curve, where $y \geq 0$, for $0 \leq t \leq 1$.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! So would I need to have another parameterisation of the form $(t,-\sqrt{t-t^2},\sqrt{1-t})$

Comment: Yes, that parametrization covers the other half of the curve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your parametrization is correct, you need to take $t$ from 0 to $2\pi$. This is because your $x$ and $y$ coordinates describe a circle shifted 1/2 units on the $x$ axis, so if you want the complete circle, you need $t\in [0,2\pi]$.

I suspect you need this to compute a line integral along this curve. Note that it is closed, so the Stokes theorem might be a good option. The area enclosed inside this curve is called [Viviani's window](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viviani%27s_curve).

Comment: Thank you! Would you be able to advise me on the second parameterisation?

Comment: As Andrew D. Hwang said, the second parametrization is incomplete, i would not use it. There is however another option:
$$
x(\theta)=r(\theta)\cos\theta, \quad y(\theta)=r(\theta)\sin\theta, \quad z=\sqrt{1-x^2(\theta)-y^2(\theta)}
$$
with $\theta \in [-\pi/2, \pi/2]$, and $r(\theta)=\cos{\theta}$.

Comment: I understand that the current parametrization is incomplete however would i be able to complete it by having two separate parametrizations like $(t,\sqrt{t-t^2},\sqrt{1-t})$ and $(t,-\sqrt{t-t^2},\sqrt{1-t})$?

Comment: Yes, but in practice you do not want to have to deal with two parametrizations, you will have twice as work to do!

Comment: Yes I definitely agree haha! It's just more to do with clarifying the concept of parametrization. I wanted to make sure I understood it properly. Thank you very much :)